# Use AND and NOT in xPath

Tags: html, xpath

I have the following issue at hand where I need to get part of the text without including `a` tag. just to be more clear, I have the following code:

```
<div class="field-item even">
   <p> text text text</p>
   <p> text text text <a class="people-articles">text text</a> text text</p>
   <p> text text text</p>
</div>
```

So I'm trying to get the text inside the `p` tag but not the `a class="people-articles"`. and here what I've done so far but its not working

```
//div[@class="field-item even"] and [not a(@class='people-articles')]
```

Can someone tell me what am i doing wrong? and how to obtain `p` without `a` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should be straight forward.

```
//div[@class="field-item even"]/p[not(a[@class="people-articles"])]/text()
```

Comment: it still grabs the a tag!

Comment: add /text() if you want the contents only